# make div change height dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a page with 3 rows. The first row is a fixed height of 150px and the last row is a fixed height of 120px. I need the middle row to adjust according to the height of the window so that all three rows are visible and there are no scroll bars visible. The middle row must adjust dynamically so that even after loading if you move the browser window to another screen that is smaller the middle row must adjust accordingly. Secondly the middle row must have it's content aligned vertically middle and horizontally center. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: please post your code also?

Comment: You can get window height from `$(window).height()` and then compute height of containers, btw using `position:fixed;` for all main containers is horribile way to design layout.

Comment: using 100vh to get height from css is much better than using JS. Also your code has a dependency on Jquery

Comment: Duplicate - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/90178/make-a-div-fill-the-height-of-the-remaining-screen-space?rq=1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CSS for the height:

```
.first-row {
   height: 150px;
}

.middle-row {
   height: calc(100vh - 150px - 120px);
}

.last-row {
   height: 120px;
}
```

Comment: I was going to make a pen using flexbox but @Kevin Farrugia beat me to it. It's definately better to use that than " display: table-cell;"

Comment: Remember those techniques are not always supported:

calc: http://caniuse.com/#feat=calc
viewport units: http://caniuse.com/viewport-units/embed/

Comment: Thank you Ben your solution worked. Now how do I vertically align the middle row content pls?

Comment: So I'd use flexbox to be honest - a great guide here: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/ but if it's too advanced and you know your content height you can add a margin or padding to the top which is half the height - half the height of your content. This can be done in a calc function too, for example if your content has 40px height, margin-top: calc(50% - 20px); Let me know how you get on. If you're struggling create a codepen and I'll help you

Comment: No worries - there should be a tick under the number of votes which you can click

Answer (score 0):

Run the code snippet in full page mode (!). Use css `calc` function to automatically calculate the height of middle container.

```css
body { 
  margin: 0; 
}
.top {
  background-color: #f0f0f0;
  height: 150px;
}
.bottom {
  background-color: #ddd;
  height: 120px;
}
.middle {
  background-color: teal;
  display: table-cell;
  height: calc(100vh - 270px);
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 100vw;
}
```

```html
<div class="top">TOP</div>
<div class="middle">MIDDLE</div>
<div class="bottom">BOTTOM</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Personally the cleanest solution is using `flexbox`:

```
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.dynamic {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
}
```

http://codepen.io/kevinfarrugia/pen/wzOqGo?editors=1100#0

Comment: Flexbox is the better solution, i was just making a codepen!

Answer (score 0):

As suggested, try using flexbox:

```
<style>
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column wrap;
  align-items: stretch;
  height: 100%;
}
.row{}
.row.row1{height: 150px;}
.row.row2{flex: 1 1 auto;}
.row.row3{height: 120px;}
</style>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row row1">First row</div>
  <div class="row row2">Middle row</div>
  <div class="row row3">Final row</div>
</div>
```

Don't forget to add your vendor prefixes when using this.

Answer (score 0):

I use flexboxes for these things: [A Complete Guide to Flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

```css
.container {  
  display: flex;
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.header {
  height: 50px;
  background-color: green;
  flex: 0 0;
}

.footer {
  height: 30px;  
  background-color: red;
  flex: 0 0;
}

.content {
  background-color: blue;
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  min-height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="header"></div>
  <div class="content"></div>
  <div class="footer"></div>
<div>
```